# How do I save my notes while pressing the save icon in my AddNotesScreen.js file

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to build a notes app, I have implemented the navigations functionality in my app, now when I click on add icon in my InitialScreen.js file it navigates to the AddNotesScreen but the problem is that I am unable to save my notes while pressing the save icon at the top right side of the AddNotesScreen page.

How to save my notes?

The codes are attached below !

````
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
  ImageBackground,
  Button,
} from "react-native";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import HeaderButton from "../components/HeaderButton";

const AddNotesScreen = (props) => {
  const [currentNoteTitle, setCurrentNoteTitle] = useState("");
  const [currentNoteContent, securrentNoteContent] = useState("");

  const notesTitleHandler = (enterednotes) => {
    setCurrentNoteTitle(enterednotes);
  };

  const notesContentHandler = (enterdContent) => {
    securrentNoteContent(enterdContent);
  };

  const Values = () => {
    return console.log({ currentNoteTitle }, { currentNoteContent });
  };

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}
    >
      <ScrollView>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/05/11/39/rain-316580_960_720.jpg",
          }}
          style={styles.imgbg}
        >
          <View style={styles.notestitle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputtitle}
              multiline={true}
              placeholder="Title"
              placeholderTextColor="#fff"
              onChangeText={notesTitleHandler}
              value={currentNoteTitle}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.notescontent}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.cont}
              multiline={true}
              numberOfLines={30}
              placeholder="Content"
              placeholderTextColor="#fff"
              onChangeText={notesContentHandler}
              value={currentNoteContent}
            />
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </ScrollView>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

AddNotesScreen.navigationOptions = (navData) => {
  return {
    headerRight: (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Save"
          iconName="ios-save"
          onPress={() => {
            navData.navigation.navigate("Notes");
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    ),
  };
};```

This is app.js file

[![][1]][1]

This is the InitialScreen.js

[![][2]][2]

This is the AddNotesScreen.js 

[![][3]][3]

[![][4]][4]

This is Navigator.js file

[![][5]][5]

This is the SearchNotesScreen.js file


[![][6]][6]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gosv.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhNDX.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMRws.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uUsf.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/flAWo.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGOPZ.png
````

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors or any other text. Copy the original text to your question, and use the code format tool when needed.

Comment: Ok, I will share my code here !!

Comment: @JamesZ I have added the code itself, can you please check and let me know.

Comment: At least it looks to me that there's significantly less code now + you've left the pictures as broken items inside the code.